# Was Lagrange the first to have used generalized coordinates?

Tags: mathematics, physics, biographical-details, lagrange

I was wondering if Lagrange was the first to use generalized coordinates as defined by their [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) article.

Comment: You should probably copy that definition here for it to be easily visible for everyone.

Comment: Depends. The angle coordinate for the pendulum used by Newton et al., or Euler's angles for a rigid body were what came to be derived as generalized coordinates. Lagrange was first to conceptualize them as such in a general variational framework.